# Mount Hidden USB device

Tags: bash, mount, usb, macos

I am not able to see an usb devide with my Macbook. Not available on Disk utility.

But I can see it with ioreg -> see THISDEVICE

```
ioreg -p IOUSB                  
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id XXXXXXXXXXX, retain 22>
  +-o AppleUSBXHCI Root Hub Simulation@14000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id XXXX, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (465 ms), retain$
  | +-o USB2.0 Hub@14100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id XXXXX, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 16>
  |   +-o USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter@14120000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100051aaf, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 12$
  |   +-o THISDEVICE@14110000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id XXXXXXXXX, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (3 ms), retain 16>
  +-o AppleUSBXHCI Root Hub Simulation@01000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id XXXXXXX, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (308 ms), retain$
```

How can I manage to mount it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You removed all information about what this device is. Why do you think it's an USB storage device, and you should be able to mount it?

Comment: This is a sport watch. I would like to download activity data from it. There is a software provided by the watch company in order to connect to the watch, but for privacy respect reason I dont want to use it. I am beginner in this subject but if this software can mount it, why can't I ?(expect if encrypted device or something else)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in the end it is about writing a driver for using a commercial product.

Comment: Unless we can see the device details we're not going to be able to give you any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a sport watch, it likely has a proprietary interface, and is not an USB storage device.

So no, the software provided with it doesn't "mount it". And you cannot "mount it" either.

You can reverse-engineer the protocol (or someone else could, in principle; if you could do that yourself, you wouldn't have to ask here) and write your own driver. But even then you cannot "mount it". You can communicate with it using the proprietary protocol.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I undertand now !